# Laravel ReflectionException: class does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is driving me insane but maybe (or probably) I am just missing something.

I'm trying to install GrafiteCMS and have followed the [docs](https://docs.grafite.ca/cms/) (Complex Setup). Admin area etc. works fine but I can't get the controllers (generated through vendor:publish) in the folder `Controllers/Cms` to work. I am getting the error:

> Class Cms\PagesController does not exist

The controller has the following namespace and is named `PagesController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Cms;
```

The autoload classmap looks correct, too:

> ```
> 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Cms\\PagesController' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Controllers/Cms/PagesController.php',
> ```

So what am I missing? It relates to all controllers inside the Cms directory.

Comment: What is result `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @Davit it doesn't work because of the same error.

Comment: See my  new answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. They should update the code. 
For anyone with the same issue:

They are publishing the cms-routes file with just the namespace `Cms` which is wrong. It has to be the full namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Cms`. So edit your cms-routes to look like this:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Cms', 'middleware' => ['cms-language', 'cms-analytics']], function () {
    Route::get('', 'PagesController@home');
    Route::get('pages', 'PagesController@all');
    Route::get('page/{url}', 'PagesController@show');
    Route::get('p/{url}', 'PagesController@show');

    Route::get('gallery', 'GalleryController@all');
    Route::get('gallery/{tag}', 'GalleryController@show');

    Route::get('blog', 'BlogController@all');
    Route::get('blog/{url}', 'BlogController@show');
    Route::get('blog/tags/{tag}', 'BlogController@tag');

    Route::get('faqs', 'FaqController@all');

    Route::get('events', 'EventsController@calendar');
    Route::get('events/{month}', 'EventsController@calendar');
    Route::get('events/all', 'EventsController@all');
    Route::get('events/date/{date}', 'EventsController@date');
    Route::get('events/event/{id}', 'EventsController@show');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

RouteServiceProvider code must be this .

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(function() { 
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
        require base_path('routes/cms.php');  // if it is not exists error occurs 
    });
}
```

Check it

Comment: See my answer. But I tried your solution anyways but it doesn't work. I think your solution is for the other setup type. Don't know, strange package tbh. But thank you anyways!

Comment: I try only this 3 steps

Comment: 1)composer require grafite/cms 2)php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Grafite\Cms\GrafiteCmsProvider" and 3)php artisan grafite:cms

Comment: In 3-rd step will message `Please confirm that you have a database set and configured in your .env file. (
yes/no) [no]:
 > y` after it I pass `y` and all work perfect

Comment: You did the simple setup but my issue related to the complex setup. You can try it, too if you have the time but I think it won't work, too.

Comment: Your solution is perfect but my answer also must be work.

Comment: Also you can copy all initial `cms.php` routes into `web.php` and delete `cms.php` file

Comment: Yes you can. But than you also have to add the namespace to the controller name in the routes else it won't work :)

Comment: That case not need, because when you in web.php it is automatically add `App\Http\Controllers` namespace before your routes

Comment: And for this responsible `Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(function() { 
        require base_path('routes/web.php');` this part

Comment: In my answer add also `base_path('routes/cms.php')` file and automatically all routes in `cms.php` in namespace must be add prefix `App\Http\Controllers`

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this sooner and help everyone! Thank you so much @Davit for helping with this. It's hard to make sure everything works great with simple and complex setup, if you guys have any suggestions for better documentation I'm happy to update it!